# glup.inject {relative:true} still creates a rootSlash

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I'm using gulp task to inject my javascript files:

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
var target = gulp.src('./public/index.html');
var sources = gulp.src(config.appjs.concat(config.appcss), {read: false} );

return target.pipe(inject(sources),
    {

        relative: true,
        addRootSlash : false
        // ignorePath: /[^/]/
        // ignorePath: "/(\.\.\/)?\//",

        // ignorePath: '/public'

    })
    .pipe(wiredep({
           ignorePath: "^/"
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

however i still see the `/public` instead of

`<script src="public/js/config/app.js"></script>`

here:

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="/public/js/config/app.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/components/home-component.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/components/login-component.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/components/progress-bar-component.js"></script>
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the options incorrectly. Right now you're passing them into `pipe()` but they need to go into `inject()`. It should be this:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {

    var target = gulp.src('./public/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src('./public/**/*.js', { read: false });

    return target.pipe(inject(sources, { relative: true, addRootSlash: false }))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            ignorePath: "^/"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```